# formatting number with exactly two decimals issue

Tags: javascript, math

I'm facing an issue, and i would love if some one explains me what is going wrong with my function.

see the code below:

if i run => number(10000.88, 2)

Can anyone explain me why to output 10000.87 instead of 10000.88

where if i run number(11111.88, 2) the output is correct 11111.88
all other outputs are correct.

```js
function number(value, decPos) {
        
  return Math.floor(Math.abs(value) * Math.pow(10, decPos)) / Math.pow(10, decPos);
       
}

document.write("<div>" + number(10, 2) + '</div>');
document.write("<div>" + number(10.8888, 2) + '</div>');
document.write("<div>" + number(100.8888, 2) + '</div>');
document.write("<div>" + number(1000.88, 2) + '</div>');
document.write("<div>" + number(10000.888, 2) + '</div>');
// magic
document.write("<div>" + number(10000.88, 2) + '</div>');

document.write("<div>" + number(100000.8888, 2) + '</div>');

// magic
document.write("<div>" + number(8368.88, 2) + '</div>');

document.write("<div>" + number(11111.8888, 2) + '</div>');
document.write("<div>" + number(11111.88, 2) + '</div>');
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Do you realize there is toFixed()?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: Using toFixed will not fix my issue, because numbers can have not only 2 decimals points, for example (1111.88787).toFixed(2) will equal 1111.89

Comment: I removed the `Math.floor(` and that worked for the first rounding error, because it was dropping the decimal, `10000.88 * 100` returns `1000087.999999` instead of expected `1000088`

Answer (score 1):

This is a rounding error, accuracy cannot be guaranteed using doubles or floats.

Answer (score 1):

That's not how rounding works, you would be getting inaccurate numbers.

But if you must:

```
function subdec(value, decimals)
{
    decimals = decimals || 2;
    var parts = value.toString().split('.');

    if (parts[1]) {
        parts[1] = parts[1].substr(0, decimals);
        return parseFloat(parts.join('.'));
    }

    return value;
}
```

Add a call to this function to your `number ()` function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function that generates expected results.

```
function number(value, decPos) { 
    str = String(value).split(".");
    if (str[1]) {
        return str[0]+"."+str[1].substring(0, decPos);
    }
    return str[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I adjusted your code a bit so as to take advantage of the `.toFixed()`  function. I made it so the `decPos` also determines how many decimal places `.toFixed()` will cut off at. Is this the functionality you’re looking for?

```js
function number(value, decPos) {
        
  return Math.floor((Math.abs(value) * Math.pow(10, decPos)).toFixed(decPos)) / Math.pow(10, decPos);
       
}

document.write("<div>" + number(10, 2) + '</div>');
document.write("<div>" + number(10.8888, 2) + '</div>');
document.write("<div>" + number(100.8888, 2) + '</div>');
document.write("<div>" + number(1000.88, 2) + '</div>');
document.write("<div>" + number(10000.888, 2) + '</div>');
// magic
document.write("<div>" + number(10000.88, 2) + '</div>');

document.write("<div>" + number(100000.8888, 2) + '</div>');

// magic
document.write("<div>" + number(8368.88, 2) + '</div>');

document.write("<div>" + number(11111.8888, 2) + '</div>');
document.write("<div>" + number(11111.88, 2) + '</div>');
document.write("<div>" + number(10000.888, 3) + '</div>');
// magic
document.write("<div>" + number(10000.88, 3) + '</div>');
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```